# jQuery date picker and time picker do not work when fields are dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using below jQuery code to generate dynamic input fields (multiple) and it includes time pickers and date pickers, but they don't work.

```
$('#add_another_event').click(function() 
    {
        var $address = $('#sub_events');
        var num = $('.clonedAddress').length; // there are 5 children inside each address so the prevCloned address * 5 + original
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
        var newElem = $address.clone().attr('id', 'address' + newNum).addClass('clonedAddress');

        //set all div id's and the input id's
        newElem.children('div').each (function (i) {
            this.id = 'input' + (newNum*5 + i);
        });

        newElem.find('input').each (function () {
            this.id = this.id + newNum;
            this.name = this.name + newNum;
        });

        if (num > 0) {
            $('.clonedAddress:last').after(newElem);
        } else {
            $address.after(newElem);
        }


        $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');              

    });
```

These are the fields I clone

```
<p><label>Art Space </label>
<input id="as_name" name="as_name" class="txt-input small" type="text">
<input id="as_id" name="as_id" class="txt-input small" type="hidden"></p>
<p><label>Start Date </label>
<input id="start_date" name="start_date" class="datepicker txt-input small" type="text"></p>
<p><label>End Date </label>
<input id="end_date" name="end_date" class="datepicker txt-input small" type="text"></p>
<p><label>Opening Hours </label>
From : <input style="width: 100px" id="time_from" name="time_from" class="timepicker txt-input small" type="text">
To : <input style="width: 100px" id="time_to" name="time_to" class="timepicker txt-input small" type="text">
</p>
```

Time Picker and Date picker

```
  $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        hourGrid: 4,
        minuteGrid: 10,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
    });

    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

My issue is above pickers are not shown when the fields are clone.

I tried with jQuery `.live()` but it doesn't work. I'm not an jQuery expert.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/MkhZ2/17/

Comment: shouldn't `var $address = $('#sub_events');` be `var address = $('#sub_events');`? (without the `$`)

Comment: @elcodedocle prefixing with `$` is a common convention indicating that the variable holds a jQuery collection.

Comment: Any help, still I was not able to figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-initialize the date/time pickers on your new elements and clear the classes that were added by the UI widget:

```
$('.datepicker', newElem).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker()
```

In this case, providing your new collection as the context so that you don't search the entire document.

---

This is showing one of the pitfalls with cloning vs templating. If you used a template to generate your new forms, you wouldn't risk copying data and classes which may affect the way the way widgets are constructed in the new form. In your case, you need to remove the `hasDatepicker` class which is applied by the UI and prevents new datepickers from being initialized on the input. However, you also can't use the cleanup method `datepicker('destroy')` because there isn't actually a datepicker on the new nodes. So you end up having to do cleanup manually.

Comment: Place it right before `$('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');`. You will also need to add a line for the timepicker.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MkhZ2/24/ here's a working example; see update for explanation

Answer (score 0):

You must invoke

```
$('target_selector').datepicker();
```

for each dynamically added element.