# To generate a cloned div with html controls , dynamic ID and listeners for the elements in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone, jquery-clone

I want to copy a div and all its content, to generate a cloned div (for example, adding lines to a invoice dinamically). I need to clone the content of the div, including html controls, dynamic ID and listeners for the elements in DIV!!

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

[image]

The code works but it is not cloning the entire DIV it also Clone the Text box ID can some one help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>

<style>
body
{
    background: none !important;
}
</style>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <title>      Dynamically create input fields- jQuery </title>


    <link href="theme/css/ui/ui.base.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

    <link href="theme/css/themes/black_rose/ui.css" rel="stylesheet" title="style" media="all" />



    <!--[if IE 6]>

    <link href="theme/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />



    <script src="theme/js/pngfix.js"></script>

    <script>

      /* Fix IE6 Transparent PNG */

      DD_belatedPNG.fix('.logo, ul#dashboard-buttons li a, .response-msg, #search-bar input');



    </script>

    <![endif]-->

 <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          var i = 1;
        $('#addNew').live('click', function() {
            var getParentId = $(this).closest('fieldset').attr('id');
            var getParentId1 = $('#'+getParentId);
            i = $('#'+getParentId+' p  input').size();
          if( i > 6 ) {
            alert("Limitation upto 5");
            return false;
          }
          $('<p><input type="text" id="p_new" name="p_new_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="I am New" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(getParentId1);
          i++;
          return false;
        });

        $('#remNew').live('click', function() {
          if( i > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
          }
          return false;
        });

        // Duplicate Query Block
        var addQueryBlock = $('#queryblock');
        var j = $('#queryblockfld').size() + 1;
        $('#addNewQueryBlock').live('click', function() {
          if( j > 6 ) {
            alert("Limitation upto 5");
            return false;
          }
          $('<fieldset id="queryblock' + j +'" name="queryblock' + j +'"><legend>Query Block' + j + '</legend><div style="float:right;" id="addqueryblock"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" id="remNewFieldset"> &#8211; </a><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" id="addNewQueryBlock">+</a></div><div id="addinput"><p><input type="text" id="p_new1" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="addNew">Add</a><input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" value="" placeholder="input2" /></p></div></fieldset>').appendTo(addQueryBlock);
          j++;
          return false;
        });

         $('#remNewFieldset').live('click', function() {
          if( j > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('fieldset').remove();
          j--;
          }
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>

</head>


  <body>
    <h2>
      Dynamically Add Another Input Box
    </h2>

    <div id="queryblock">
      <fieldset id="queryblockfld" name="queryblockfld">
        <legend>
          Query Block
        </legend>
        <div style="float:right;" id="addqueryblock">
          <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#" id="addNewQueryBlock">+</a></div>
          <div id="addinput">
            <p>
              <input type="text" id="p_new3" name="p_new3" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
              <a href="#" id="addNew"> Add </a> Wlcome to my world
              <input type="text" id="input2"  name="input2" value="" placeholder="input2" />
            </p>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Simply use jQuery `.clone()` method :)

Comment: But what about the Input field inside the DIV will that also be cloned to new name kinldy check the below URL I tried that too http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/ but a but sticky.

Comment: Well if you want to have dynamic ID and listeners attached then your question is incorrect. You are not looking to clone an element :) What you want is to be able to create HTML element with certain parameters. I think you need to make a factory... :)

Comment: I just finding the way to do it. I feel I did some what but not the complete function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a Long Search I found a working code which does what I wanted. Kindly refer the link

```
<div id="events_wrapper">
<div id="sub_events">
<p><label>Art Space </label>
<input type="text" id="as_name" name="as_name" class="txt-input small"/>
<input type="hidden" id="as_id" name="as_id" class="txt-input small"/>                                      
</p>

<p><label>Start Date </label>
<input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" class="datepicker txt-input small"/>

<label>End Date </label>
 <input type="text" id="end_date" name="end_date" class="datepicker txt-input small" />
</p>

<p><label>Opening Hours </label>
 From : <input style="width: 100px" type="text" id="time_from" name="time_from" class="timepicker txt-input small" />

To : <input style="width: 100px" type="text" id="time_to" name="time_to" class="timepicker txt-input small"/> </p>                                                    
</div>
     <br/>
<input type="button" id="add_another_event" name="add_another_event" value="Add Another" />
```

JS Function:

```
$('#add_another_event').click(function() 
    {
        alert('test');var $address = $('#sub_events');
        var num = $('.clonedAddress').length; // there are 5 children inside each address so the prevCloned address * 5 + original
        var newNum = num + 1;
        var newElem = $address.clone().attr('id', 'address' + newNum).addClass('clonedAddress');

        //set all div id's and the input id's
        newElem.children('div').each (function (i) {
            this.id = 'input' + (newNum*5 + i);
        });

        newElem.find('input').each (function () {
            this.id = this.id + newNum;
            this.name = this.name + newNum;
        });

        if (num > 0) {
            $('.clonedAddress:last').after(newElem);
        } else {
            $address.after(newElem);
        }

        $('.datepicker', newElem).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
        $('#btnDel').removeAttr('enabled'); 
    });       

$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

[Also Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052059/jquery-date-picker-and-time-picker-do-not-work-when-fields-are-dynamically-creat) [Jquery date picker and time picker do not work when fields are dynamically created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052059/jquery-date-picker-and-time-picker-do-not-work-when-fields-are-dynamically-creat)

Hope this will help some one.!

Working Example of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/MkhZ2/24/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using jQuery's `.clone()` method. Consider the following code :

```
//first clone your div
clonedDiv = $('#IdOfYourDIV').clone();

//use .attr() method to change the id
$(clonedDiv).attr('id','YourDynamicID');
```

Now your 'cloned' div is ready. But the handlers binded using the ID of the first div won't work on the clonedDIV.

Answer (score 1):

I was dev something like this so my solution was very simple. Use clone to duplicate your `div` and `appentTo` set assuming the `div` are contained by `body`.

```
$("#btn_act").click(function(){
   var body = $("body"); //Where is contained the object
   var obj = $("#myDiv"); //Object who will be cloned
   var e = obj.clone(true).appendTo(body);
   $(e).find("input").each(function(){
       //ie: myInput0, myInput1 will be deleted
       if ($(this).attr("id") != 'myInput'){
          $(this).remove();
       }
   });
});
```

Think this would help you if you still need an small solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicater' + i);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    clone.onclick = duplicate; // event handlers are not cloned
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

not `duplicetor` but `duplicater` :) then it will not show an error in console and add a cloned div

why wouldn't it clone input fields? it will clone it...

Comment: The Div is alone Duplicated not the ID of the elements inside the DIV.

Comment: ins't 'duplicater' the div's ID not the elements inside it? or am i not understanding something?

Comment: The DIV id is updated to a new Id, But the Input field Id are not updated to a new name?