# How to get HTML cloned form values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the values from my form when the user clones the row. When I clone the rows are the id still the same? If so how do I make the new rows to have a unique id?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $button = $('#add-row'),
    $row = $('.period-row').clone();

  $button.click(function() {
    $row.clone().insertBefore($button);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="heading">Please select appointment period</h3>
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form action="#" id="date-form" name="date-form" method="POST">
    <div class="period-row">
      <label for="start">From:</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="start[]" id="start">
      <label for="end">To:</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="end[]" id="end">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add-row" name="add-row" value="add period" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple answer: don't. Use common classes instead.

Comment: Also the title and the question are asking two different things.

Comment: The ids are indeed the same when you clone them. As @Rory suggests, consider whether you need ids at all (you can wrap the `input` and text with the `label` and remove the `for` attribute).

Comment: Similar answer by donofden <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768222/to-generate-a-cloned-div-with-html-controls-dynamic-id-and-listeners-for-the-e/38595697>

Comment: When you post the form, what matters is the `name` attribute of the inputs. If name is the same, you get an array of values posted to server with that name. So it shouldn't be a problem to have duplicate names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you want and to do it on the proper way you have to use class on the input and not id because the id is unique. But I hope this code will help you.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $button = $('#add-row'),
  $row = $('.period-row').clone();

  $button.click(function() {
    let from = $('#start').val();
    let to = $('#end').val();
    $row.clone().insertBefore($button).addClass('active');
    $('.period-row.active').find("#start").val(from);
    $('.period-row.active').find("#end").val(from);
    $('.period-row').removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="heading">Please select appointment period</h3>
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form action="#" id="date-form" name="date-form" method="POST">
    <div class="period-row">
      <label for="start">From:</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="start[]" id="start">
      <label for="end">To:</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" name="end[]" id="end">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add-row" name="add-row" value="add period" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```